# how can i extract nft collections from etherscan.io?

Tags: blockchain, javascript, etherscan

Just like major NFT Market places like opensea , foundation , rarible , x2y2.io have been extracting all the collections and their NFT's which are available in etherscan.io. I am seeking ways on how this is being implemented , I dont find collection retrieval in etherscan.io dev docs. Can anyone help me with this ?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan is simply an online web2 interface that allows users to clearly see block data transaction by transaction. In order to extract all the data for NFTs created, you'll need to create a crawler that finds ERC721 contracts on the blockchain.

The process looks something like this:

1. Dictate your `fromBlock` and `toBlock` range
2. Create a web3 instance of the each contract in the block range
3. Call supportsInterface method on the contract to check if it exists, using ERC721 ID (`0x80ac58cd`)
4. If it does, record whichever metrics you are looking for.

This will return you all tx's which have an ERC721 signature (note that this obviously **won't** return you the sacred content of each NFT, rather just things like the contract location and token address). Once you have these, you can get more specific datas by using things like [this](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-collections), provided by OpenSea, for retrieving collections etc...

Comment: OP should also check against the NFT 1155 type by doing a check against the ERC 1155 Interface ID `0xd9b67a26`

Comment: @Potion thats correct :)

Comment: Thanks for the help ! have any docs on it step by step about the execution ? @XaEK